# Click event on a button with SetInterval Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm not able to figure out how this can be accomplished. I'm working on the chrome extension and I have a setInterval method which monitors a button on a page and when its clicked, it runs a function. but the problem is, when I click the button, the function runs multiple times and I clearly understand this is because of the Interval function, but I want the  setInterval to run always on this page so that I can monitor if the button is clicked or not. Below is my code

```
$(function(){
var url=window.location.href;
findAction(url);
}

 function findAction(url){

        setInterval(()=>{
        Acceptbtn = $("[slot=primary-content-area")[4].querySelector("sn-inbox");
        
                if(Acceptbtn !== undefined && Acceptbtn !== null){
                Acceptbtn.addEventListener('click', myFunction);                
                }

            function myFunction() {
            console.log("clicked");
            runAction(url)          
                };
    
    },1000);

}
```

Is there any way to tackle this situation or have I made something simple, complicated or Is my approach completely wrong.?

Below is the Div which my extension monitors for the Accept button -
[image]

And once the Accept button is clicked, this is what happens
[image]

The Interval method keeps checking for this button and once found and I click on it, I want the runAction(url) function to execute. With my current code, the function gets executed but multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Only add an event listener once

Also the selector is incorrect if `sn-inbox` is a class and `[slot=primary-content-area]` was missing a `]`

Here I delegate - if you delegate to the closest static container (here document, because I do not know the closest container in your case), you can ALWAYS find the button when it is there:

```
  const url = window.location.href;
  $(document).on("click", "[slot=primary-content-area]", function() {
    if ($(this).index() === 3) { // 0 based - so the 4th slot
      const $inbox = $(this).find(".sn-inbox");
      if ($inbox.length > 0) {
        $inbox.html("running");
        runAction(url)
      }
    }
  })
```

Example code to execute the functions:

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/p93cj0Le/

```js
$(function() {
  const runAction = url => console.log("running", url);

  const url = window.location.href;
  $(document).on("click", "[slot=primary-content-area]", function() {
    if ($(this).index() === 3) { // 0 based
      const $inbox = $(this).find(".sn-inbox");
      if ($inbox.length > 0) {
        $inbox.html("running");
        runAction(url)
      }
    }
  })
  
  // testing the code
  setInterval(() => {
    $("#container").html(`<div>
     <div slot="primary-content-area"></div>
     <div slot="primary-content-area"></div>
     <div slot="primary-content-area"></div>
     <div slot="primary-content-area"><button class="sn-inbox">Click</button></div>
   </div>`)
  }, 5000)
  setTimeout(() => $("#container").html(""), 2000)
})
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried the above code and I get the error  'acceptbtn.on is not a function at addListener'. Could you tell me how your approach uses a boolean 'added', how will it work the second time.? because the added will become true when the button is clicked and how will it get set back to false.?

Comment: Since I did not actually have any HTML to play around with, I could not test my code.
I have changed the added to clearing the interval - that is much more elegant

Comment: ok. but once the interval is cleared, how will it start the next time.? I placed the click function inside the interval method so that the Accept button is always monitored on this page and as soon as the button appears and I click on it, run the function runAction();. I have updated my questions adding screenshot to make it more clear.

Comment: If the button appears and stays, then no need to have the interval running

Comment: Right, but the button does not stay. Its basically a Chat Accept button. Once the Accept button is clicked, the button goes off. But once a new Chat arrives, the Accept button will re appear in the same div. Do I need to think of any other approach for this problem. This is the only part which is pending for me to complete this.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not sure how to implement this using my chrome extension. I do not have access to modify this page except using chrome extension. As per this code, I add another container.? Very sorry to ask this again, I'm still learning JS.

Comment: @Sharon Please see the updated answer. The code is the same but I show you what code YOU need to run

Comment: Not sure if I got this code correctly but as per my understanding, this runs the functions when it finds the button. So the code works. but how do I restart this code again once its executed. Please correct me If I'm wrong here